# "Il faut la taille mince et le prix léger" : signification, origine ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

Dans l'avant-propos d'un ouvrage on lit :

> L'organisation en crédits d'enseignement entraîne des variations entre les Universités. Les deux premières années de licence (L1 et L2) ont cependant suffisamment de points
> communs pour proposer des livres utiles à tous. Avec la collection Express, vous allez vite à l'essentiel.
> Pour aller vite, **il faut la taille mince et le prix léger.**
> Il faut aussi une organisation en fiches courtes et nombreuses pour vous permettre de
> ne retenir que les sujets du moment, semestre après semestre.

Quelle est la signification et l'origine de l'expression "il faut la taille mince et le prix léger" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La ***taille mince*** est une métaphore sur le tour de taille. Ici, ça indique que l'ouvrage en question n'est pas trop volumineux, ne contient rien de superflu.

Le ***prix léger*** est aussi une image. Elle indique que le prix modéré de l'ouvrage est un autre de ses atouts. On aurait pu écrire ***et le prix léger qui va avec*** puisque ce prix est une conséquence de la « sveltesse » du livre.

Je ne pense pas qu'il faille chercher une origine antérieure pour cette expression, ce doit simplement être une création de son auteur(e).

Answer (score 3):

Apparemment il ne s'agit pas d'une expression toute faite, mais tout simplement d'une construction libre par laquelle l'auteur a voulu expliquer en deux métaphores que deux nécessités sont des condition de base pour être rapide. La taille mince est une comparaison entre l'individu qui se maintient en forme et n'a pas de surpoids, d'où la possibilité qu'il a de se déplacer rapidement, avec les ouvrages de petite taille, parce qu'ils sont vite lus et communiquent une certaine information (vitale, faut-il croire), de façon rapide.
La seconde comparaison est moins évidente. « Prix léger », à mon avis ne peut pas être compris comme « le prix du livre » ; il est apparent que « prix » est une métaphore pour « l'effort nécessaire dans la compréhension ou  la justification de l'information fournie » ; il faut donc que l'ouvrage fournisse au lecteur des justifications suffisamment convaincantes à moindre effort.